# Undefined dictionaries in my main function

Tags: python

```
def monday_availability(openhours_M): #openhours_M = number hours pool is open
hourone = int(input('Input the first hour in the range of hours the guard can work'))
hourlast = int(input('Input the last hour in the range of hours the guard'))
hour = 1
availability_M = []
while hour <= openhours_M:
    if hour >= hourone & hour <= hourlast:
        availability_M.append(1)
    else:
        availability_M.append(0)
return availability_M
```

Above is a function gathering the availability of a lifeguard and storing the hours a guard can work as a 1 in availability list or a 0 if they cannot.  I return this list with the intent of adding it to a dictionary in the function below.

```
def guard_availability(guards, openhours_M, openhours_T, openhours_W, 
openhours_R, openhours_F, openhours_S, openhours_Su):
continueon = 1
while continueon == 1:
    name = input('Input guards name of lifeguard to update availability' )
    availability = {}
    days = {}

    if openhours_M != 0:
        monday_availability(openhours_M)
    if openhours_T != 0:
        tuesday_availability(openhours_T)
    if openhours_W != 0:
        wednesday_availability(openhours_W)
    if openhours_R != 0:
        thursday_availability(openhours_R)
    if openhours_F != 0:
        friday_availability(openhours_F)
    if openhours_S != 0:
        saturday_availability(openhours_S)
    if openhours_Su != 0:
        sunday_availability(openhours_Su)

    days['Monday'] = availability_M
    days['Tuesday'] = availability_T
    days['Wednesday'] = availability_W
    days['Thursday'] = availability_R
    days['Friday'] = availability_F
    days['Saturday'] = availability_S
    days['Sunday'] = availability_Su
    availability[name]= days
    continueon = input('Enter 1 to add availability for another guard, 0 to stop: ')

return days
```

When I run this code, I get an error saying my availability lists are undefined even though I returned them in the functions above.  Where is the error in my understanding of returning in functions, and how can I remedy this problem.

Comment: Quote the full, exact, error details. Also, your code is not displaying indents correctly, so won't run.

Comment: should you write :  availability_M= monday_availability(openhours_M) in if condition?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Your code could be largely simplified by just acknowledging a value which says which day of the week is of interest: no need to replicate everything seven times.

Answer (score 0):

You return the dic value in your function but don't assign it to any variable. You should do it like this:

```
if openhours_M != 0:
    availability_M=monday_availability(openhours_M)
if openhours_T != 0:
    availability_T=tuesday_availability(openhours_T)
if openhours_W != 0:
    availability_W=wednesday_availability(openhours_W)
if openhours_R != 0:
    availability_R=thursday_availability(openhours_R)
if openhours_F != 0:
    availability_F=friday_availability(openhours_F)
if openhours_S != 0:
    availability_S=saturday_availability(openhours_S)
if openhours_Su != 0:
    availability_Su=sunday_availability(openhours_Su)
```

Answer (score 0):

`monday_availability(openhours_M)` **returns** a value.

Returning a variable does not assign it to anything outside the scope of that function.

If you renamed `return availability_M` to use `return foo` and update the other uses only within that function accordingly,  would the error make more sense?

Now, actually capture the result

```
 availability_M =  monday_availability(openhours_M)
```

Or even just

```
days['Monday'] = monday_availability(openhours_M)
```

Also, not seeing how that function has anything to do with Mondays. [Try to write DRY code](http://wiki.c2.com/?DontRepeatYourself)